# HTML navbar animation doesn't work

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hi guys I'm new to programming and I'm trying to build a site. I wanted a nice animation for my nabber and followed this guide (http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/),I want an animation in which the text gets underlined when you hover over it, but it doesn't work, why not? Did I write everything properly in the right places etc. and is it right to write you CSS in the head because I saw someone who had a separate file for the CSS code.

```css
  <head>
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
      }

      header{
        background-color: white;
      }

      header::after{
        content: " ";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }

      .container{
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .logo{
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      nav{
        float: right;

        font-family: 'courier';
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      }

      nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 45px;
      }

      nav li a{
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 17px 15px;
      }

      nav li a:before{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transition: all 0,3s ease-in-out 0s;
        transition: all 0,3s ease-in-out 0s;
      }

      nav li a:hover:before{
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
        transform: scaleX(1);
      }

    </style>
  </head>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">

        <img class="logo" src="file:///Users/siebe/PROJECTEN/Code/HTML/Site%20DIA/Pics/Logo%20DIA%20site.png">

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">OVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things.

**1.** You had an error here:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0,3s ease-in-out 0s;
        transition: all 0,3s ease-in-out 0s;
```

**2.** "nav li a" need to have a "relative" position.

**3.** You did not set a height for "nav li a:before"

**This works..**

```css
<head>
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
      }

      header{
        background-color: white;
      }

      header::after{
        content: " ";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }

      .container{
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .logo{
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      nav{
        float: right;

        font-family: 'courier';
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      }

      nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 45px;
      }

      nav li a{
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 17px 15px;
        position: relative;
      }

      nav li a:before{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      }

       nav li a:hover:before{
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
        transform: scaleX(1);
      }

    </style>
  </head>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">

        <img class="logo" src="file:///Users/siebe/PROJECTEN/Code/HTML/Site%20DIA/Pics/Logo%20DIA%20site.png">

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">OVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error:

```
transition: all 0,3s ease-in-out 0s;
```

You have a comma (,) instead of a period (.)

In future, try this handy CSS validation service, it will point out errors for you!

[CSS Validation](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Answer (score 0):

In your css code try changing `nav li a` to `nav ul li a` where ever you have in the style tag. That way your `<a>` tag can get the proper style.

`nav li a` would refer to a link in a list item in a navbar

`nav ul li a` would refer to a link in a list item in a list in a navbar

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
        background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
      }

      header{
        background-color: white;
      }

      header::after{
        content: " ";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }

      .container{
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .logo{
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      nav{
        float: right;

        font-family: 'courier';
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      }

      nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 45px;
      }

      nav li a{
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 17px 15px;
       
      }

      nav li a:after{
         display:block;
         content: '';
         border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
         transform: scaleX(0);  
         transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
      }

      nav li a:hover:after{
        transform: scaleX(1);
      }
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="container">

        <img class="logo" src="file:///Users/siebe/PROJECTEN/Code/HTML/Site%20DIA/Pics/Logo%20DIA%20site.png">

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">OVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
  
</header>
```

We can achieve by using `border-bottom` and `transform` css properties.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for??